# python(venv) report :The sqlite3 module is not available

Tags: python, sqlite

I use python3:venv to run telethon. However, when I run the programe in my venv env, it report me

```
telegrambaseclient.py:292: UserWarning: The sqlite3 module is not available under this Python installation and no custom session instance was given; using MemorySession.
```

I try to run `pip install sqlite3`, it report

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sqlite3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sqlite3
```

I research for some information.
I try run `pip install pysqlite3`, it report

```
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pysqlite3

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

Then I run `yum install sqlite sqlite-devel` and `pip install pysqlite3`.it's ok, but when I run my python programe to log telethon client, it also report:

```
/testvenv1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telethon/client/telegrambaseclient.py:292: UserWarning: The sqlite3 module is not available under this Python installation and no custom session instance was given; using MemorySession.
You will need to re-login every time unless you use another session storage
  warnings.warn(
```

Could you tell me how to deal with this problem?
How to install sqlite3 in python venv?

I want anyone can tell me how to install sqlite3 in python venv?